# tabu leading space affect

Tags: tabu

Leading space affecting using tabu package, any set template update needed?
Please find MEW file is as below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}

{\fontsize{8bp}{10bp}\selectfont\begin{tabu}{p{222pt}p{40pt}}
\tabucline{-}
Total non-current\break liabilities&Employee benefits\vphantom{yg}\\
Total non-current\break liabilities&Employee benefits\\
Total non-current\break liabilities&Employee benefits\\
Total non-current\break liabilities&Employee benefits\\
\tabucline{-}
\end{tabu}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- using `tabu`: you should be aware, that this package is buggy and not maintained (some fixes are available on *github*)
- for terminating of rows you should use `\\`
- function of `\break` command is unclear, so far I didn't see that it has been used in cells' contents formatting
- see, if the following MWE gives what you after:

```
 \documentclass{book} 
 \usepackage{tabu} 

 \begin{document}
{
\fontsize{8bp}{10bp}\selectfont
\tabulinesep=3pt
\begin{tabu}{p{222pt}p{40pt}} 
    \tabucline{-} 
Total non-current liabilities   &   Employee benefits   \\
Total non-current liabilities   &   Employee benefits   \\ 
Total non-current liabilities   &   Employee benefits   \\ 
Total non-current liabilities   &   Employee benefits   \\
    \tabucline{-}
\end{tabu}
} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
A I mentioned, the `tabu` is buggy. It is not clear what is your problem, howevere, instead `tabu` I would rather use simple `tabular`:

```
 \documentclass{book}
 \usepackage{tabu}

 \begin{document} 
{
\fontsize{8bp}{10bp}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{p{222pt}p{40pt}} 
    \hline
Total non-current liabilities   &   Employee benefits   \\
Total non-current liabilities   &   Employee benefits   \\ 
Total non-current liabilities   &   Employee benefits   \\ 
Total non-current liabilities   &   Employee benefits   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
} 
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Yes I understand, but tabulinesep gives extra row space for every rows which affects normal para too, that is leading increased by 3pt.

Comment: Is any other option to fix leading space issues using tabu package?

Comment: @RajeshN, sorry, I do not understood you. What you mean with *leading spae*? Provide a sketch, which show what is you problem. Let me repeat, your question is not very clear.

Comment: Please refer in the PDF output from last row 7th line leading space decreased(8.6pt base to base), all other rows correct leading space taken(12pt base to base)

{\begin{tabu}{p{222pt}p{40pt}p{40pt}p{10pt}p{40pt}}
Current tax payable&&&&\\
Employee benefits&12&&&\\
Lease liabilities
&15&&&\\
Employee benefits
&12&&&\\
Total non-current\newline liabilities&&&&\\
Total liabilities&&&&\\
\textbf{Net assets}&&&&\\
SHAREHOLDERS’ EQUITY&&&&\\
Issued capital&16&&&\\
Retained earnings&&&&\\
\textbf{Total shareholders’ equity}&&&&\\
\tabucline{-}
\end{tabu}}
{}